# immer applyPatches not updating state

Tags: immer.js

I'm trying to use immer patches to implement undo/redo functionality in my app. But for some reason, it doesn't work. I'm pasting the relevant snippet below. I confirmed that the "state" i pass to applyPatches has the new state/data, and that "patchHist[index].undo" has the correct undo state i need. There are also no errors displayed on the console, but it does not update state with the data. Am i missing something here?

```
import produce, {applyPatches, enablePatches} from 'immer';
enablePatches();
let index = -1;

function data(state:initState, action) {
return produce(
    state,
    draft => {
        switch (action.type)
            case FETCH:
            ....
            case RESET:
            applyPatches(state, patchHist[index].undo);
            break;
    },
    (patches, inversePatches) => {   
        index++;
        patchHist[index] = {
            redo: patches,
            undo: inversePatches,
        };
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to provide a code sandbox reproduction

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to increment/decrement the index in RESET case.
it will give details in detail

https://techinscribed.com/implementing-undo-redo-functionality-in-redux-using-immer/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)